# Is there a way to import rxjs into a plain js web custom component?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, custom-element

I'm trying to create web custom components using plain js. I would like to use rxjs and observables to fetch json content from a REST endpoint that I am also creating using python pyramid. However, an error - 'TypeError: global is undefined' - is being thrown when I import rxjs.

```js
import 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@6.0.0/dist/global/rxjs.umd.js';
```

also tried:

```js
import 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js';
```

I would like to NOT use npm at all.

Comment: found out how. I was supposed to put the url into a script tag and then use it in the js file as:
```js
const { Observable, from } = rxjs;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

then:

```js
const { Observable, from } = rxjs;
```

Answer (score 0):

With NodeJS and plain JS:

```
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/dist/bundles/rxjs.umd.js"></script>


   // And JS code sample...  
 
    this.networkStatus$ = rxjs.merge(
        rxjs.of(null),
        rxjs.fromEvent(window, 'online'),
        rxjs.fromEvent(window, 'offline')
    )

    this.applicationStatus$ = new rxjs.BehaviorSubject(this.getApplicationStatus());
```